# Compiling mysql connector C++ with mingw, compiling errors

Tags: c++, cmake, mysql-connector, mingw32

I'm having a problem compiling mysql connectors C++ with mingw, as posted in the official website, you should run cmake to configure the source, then run a mingw32-make... the cmake needs to have the boost library installed, so i got it and compiled it (it says many updated, 40 targets skipped and failed to update 24).

After that tried to run cmake on mysql connector source, it output no errors and work just fine, when trying to do the final step mingw32-make, it gives lots of errors, many of then are redefinitions... the log is below. Please help me i really need it.

```
    C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\bin>mingw32-make
    [  0%] Building CXX object driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/mysql_art_resultset.cpp.obj
    C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:1:0: warning: -fPIC
     ignored for target (all code is position independent) [enabled by default]
    In file included from C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_global.h:72:0,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\nativeapi/mysql_private_iface.h:57,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_util.h:30,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:31:
    C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_config.h:509:0: warning: "isnan" redefined [enabled by default]

    In file included from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:28:0:
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/math.h:480:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    In file included from C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_global.h:72:0,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\nativeapi/mysql_private_iface.h:57,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_util.h:30,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:31:
    C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_config.h:517:0: warning: "strtok_r" redefined [enabled by default]
    In file included from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr-default.h:41:0,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/gthr.h:150,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ext/atomicity.h:34,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/bits/ios_base.h:41,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ios:43,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/istream:40,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/sstream:39,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:27:
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/pthread.h:460:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    In file included from C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_global.h:72:0,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\nativeapi/mysql_private_iface.h:57,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_util.h:30,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:31:
    C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_config.h:527:0: warning: "NOMINMAX" redefined [enabled by default]
    In file included from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/c++config.h:414:0,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/iosfwd:40,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/ios:39,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/istream:40,
                     from c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/sstream:39,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:27:
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/i686-w64-mingw32/bits/os_defines.h:46:0: note: this is the location of the previous definition
    In file included from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_util.h:30:0,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:31:
    C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\nativeapi/mysql_private_iface.h:81:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    In file included from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.c
    pp:36:0:
    C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2/cppconn/exception.h:48:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2/cppconn/exception.h:52:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2/cppconn/exception.h:53:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    C:/Users/Hugo/Downloads/mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2/cppconn/exception.h:58:0: warning: ignoring #pragma warning  [-Wunknown-pragmas]
    C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:162:1: error: invalid suffix "ui64" on integer constant
    C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:162:1: error: invalid suffix "ui64" on integer constant
    In file included from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\nativeapi/mysql_private_iface.h:57:0,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_util.h:30,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:31:
    C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_global.h: In function 'double rint(double)':
    C:/MySQL/MySQL_Server_5.6/include/my_global.h:1160:35: error: 'double rint(double)' was declared 'extern' and later 'static' [-fpermissive]
    In file included from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:28:0:
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/../../../../i686-w64-mingw32/include/math.h:783:23: error: previous declaration of 'double rint(double)' [-fpermissive]
    In file included from D:/boost_1_53_0/boost/assert.hpp:81:0,
                     from D:/boost_1_53_0/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:29,
                     from D:/boost_1_53_0/boost/shared_ptr.hpp:17,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_util.h:33,
                     from C:\Users\Hugo\Downloads\mysql-connector-c++-1.1.2\driver\mysql_art_resultset.cpp:31:
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/cstdlib: At global scope:
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/cstdlib:196:11: error: '::strtoll' has not been declared
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/cstdlib:197:11: error: '::strtoull' has not been declared
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/cstdlib:219:22: error: '__gnu_cxx::strtoll' has not been declared
    c:\qt\qt5.0.1\tools\mingw\bin\../lib/gcc/i686-w64-mingw32/4.7.2/include/c++/cstdlib:220:22: error: '__gnu_cxx::strtoull' has not been declared
    driver\CMakeFiles\mysqlcppconn.dir\build.make:57: recipe for target 'driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/mysql_art_resultset.cpp.obj' failed
    mingw32-make[2]: *** [driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/mysql_art_resultset.cpp.obj] Error 1
    CMakeFiles\Makefile2:94: recipe for target 'driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/all' failed
    mingw32-make[1]: *** [driver/CMakeFiles/mysqlcppconn.dir/all] Error 2
    makefile:135: recipe for target 'all' failed
    mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 2
```

Comment: Most of these are warnings, the only errors seem to be around the ui64 type or compiler flags. Maybe the mingw32-make version is not correct?

Comment: What do you mean? You believe the problem is something in mingw32-make? I am using the mingw version imbued on Qt, so should i install a new mingw or install another kind of make tool (cmake can build for nmake,mingw32-make,make etc...)?  thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0):

The mysql connector c++ source code is garbage, unfortunately.

It redefines functions that are defined in the standard library and then includes the standard library, or depends on non-standard functions that are not included in every implementation.

Since the standard library does not check to see if its functions and structs have already been defined, you end up with multiple definition errors all over the place.

Also, the problem is made worse for you in that mysql connector has not been ported for mingw. To compile on windows you are required to use visual studio.

It get's better. They only support visual studio 8 and 9.

If you follow these instructions exactly,
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connectors/en/connector-cpp-installation-source.html
then you might be able to get it to work, but you must not deviate from any version numbers. Use an old version of cmake, an old version of visual studio. They have not tested nor do they care about compatibility with any modern versions of build tools.